# how to pass argument to child function in js

Tags: javascript

```
function checkSalary(baseSalary, bonus, tax) {
    console.log(baseSalary, bonus, tax)
    function salary(baseSalary, bonus) {
        console.log(baseSalary, bonus)
        return baseSalary + bonus;
    }
    function salary_with_tax(tax) {
        console.log(tax)

        return salary() - tax;
    }
}

console.log(checkSalary(5000, 3000, 100))
```

I want to check using salary() and salary_with_tax() but don't know how to pass the arguments.

Comment: "I want to check" .... _what_ do you want to check exactly? This question is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The thing that is odd here is that the two functions within the outer function are not called. They are simply defined. Call them somewhere to use their return value.

Comment: i mean, the result of both function with arguments i'm passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call your inner functions at some point. Something like this:

I had to make some assumptions about what you want. I returned an object with the results of each inner function.

```js
function checkSalary(baseSalary, bonus, tax) {
    console.log(baseSalary, bonus, tax)
    function salary(baseSalary, bonus) {
        console.log(baseSalary, bonus)
        return baseSalary + bonus;
    }
    function salary_with_tax(tax) {
        console.log(tax)

        return salary(baseSalary, bonus) - tax;
    }
    
    return {
      salary: salary(baseSalary, bonus),
      tax: salary_with_tax(tax)
    }
}

console.log(checkSalary(5000, 3000, 100))
```

Comment: ah yeah this is what i want to do (but don't know how): calling the inner function. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is much like many languages where you can defined functions within other functions, but until you actually *call* the function nothing happens. Just call the inner functions and get the result and do with it whatever you like.

There is also no need to re-define the arguments if theyre exactly the same names.

```js
function checkSalary(baseSalary, bonus, tax) {

    function salary() {
        
        return baseSalary + bonus;
    }
    function salary_with_tax() {
        return salary() - tax;
    }
    
    const theSalary = salary()
    const theSalaryWithTax = salary_with_tax();
    
    console.log(theSalary, theSalaryWithTax);
    
    return "Foo"; // you can "check" whatever you like here, and return something more appropriate
}

console.log(checkSalary(5000, 3000, 100))
```